# How to make an input-popup (popup dialog) in WPF?

Tags: wpf, input, dialog, popup, overlay

my wish is to get some kind of "popup" as an input dialog. I really need no big window, just a few TextBoxes.

I tried this with the WPF-Popup till i recognized it's not built for this kind of use.

Here is how it looked like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kQMc.jpg

Why i like popup?

- doesnt lock screen
- no own window
- disappears by clicking elsewhere

So how is the best way to achive the same behavior?

My approaches and problems:

- Popup: I get no LostFocus event so the TextBoxes won't trigger
  updateSourceTrigger (cannot use propertyChanged, because i need converters)
- Canvas with Visibility: Z-Index is not possible because the control
  is in a DataGrid which overlays the canvas.

Maybe i could try one global canvas in my window and re-use it for the cells, but if i need sometime another kind of popup i cannot re-use this. So the best way would be each cell can open it's own popup (input).

thx in advance